# Trouble using timer class in C#

Tags: c#, timer

basically I'm trying to implement the timer in class for my would-be very first game in C#; I want to use timers that will constantly update the player and provide certain periodic feedback, but I can't seem to get the 'timer' class to work correctly. If I use it in a loop (as shown below), it will wait 2 seconds, and then keep writing "You're Alive!" to the console with 0 delay in-between; and if I do not use the loop, the application just ends instantly.

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class MyClass
{ 
    public static void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You're alive!");
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
            MyTimer.Interval = 2000;
            MyTimer.Enabled = true;
            MyTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
            MyTimer.Start();
        }
}
```

Comment: You're making infinite timers which each one will write *You're Alive!* every 2 seconds!

Comment: here you are making infinite threads. using while(true)

Comment: Also, how would be game end? it looks an infinite game!

Comment: Oh I see; and what I pasted was essentially just a snippet to avoid people having to read extra code for no reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add below line after `MyTimer.Start();`

> Console.ReadLine();

```
static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
        MyTimer.Interval = 2000;
        MyTimer.Enabled = true;
        MyTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);
        MyTimer.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You're alive!");

    }
```